# Action Bar Tabs - Having two fragments (one being dynamic) in one tab

Tags: android, dynamic, tabs, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I am trying to create a tab that displays a list on the left hand fragment and a detailed fragment on the right. When a user clicks a list item, the right hand fragment should change to the appropriate one.

I am new to android so I used a tutorial and I know I need to do something with the tablistener:

```
     public static class TabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener 
     {
        private final Activity mActivity;
        private final String mTag;
        private final Class mClass;
        private final Bundle mArgs;
        private Fragment mFragment;
```

`public TabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz) {
            this(activity, tag, clz, null);
        }

        public TabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz, Bundle args) {
            mActivity = activity;
            mTag = tag;
            mClass = clz;
            mArgs = args;

            // Check to see if we already have a fragment for this tab, probably
            // from a previously saved state.  If so, deactivate it, because our
            // initial state is that a tab isn't shown.
            mFragment = mActivity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(mTag);
            if (mFragment != null && !mFragment.isDetached()) {
                ft = mActivity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.detach(mFragment);
                ft.commit();
            }
        }

        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            if (mFragment == null) {
                mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName(), mArgs);
                    ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
                    tabtag = mTag;
            } 
            else {
                ft.attach(mFragment);
            }
        }

        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            if (mFragment != null) {
                ft.detach(mFragment);
            }
        }

        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            //Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Reselected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }`

Another good example of what I need would be something like the Gmail app, with a list on the left, detail on the right, and keeping the action bar (mine has tabs) on top.

I understand that this listener inflates a fragment for each tab clicked, but how do I inflate a *layout* that has two fragments in it?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inflating a layout with two fragments is simple: you just specify the Class of each fragment in the layout.  But you can't mix static (layout XML-defined) and dynamic Fragments.  By which I mean, you can't dynamically instantiate a new Fragment in code and insert it into a View container (e.g., a LinearLayout) that was originally populated with Fragments in the XML.