# Unable to correctly swap fragments on actionbar tabs

Tags: android, tabs, android-fragments

Have read every question/answer on this topic but I can't get any of them to work for me.aggghh

I have 3 actionbar tabs

tab1 calls/uses a fragment that dynamically displays an "add" button

when the button is clicked I want it to remove itself 'the button fragment' and replace it with a fragment that has a bunch of EditTexts

This works as expected. However when I click another tab, eg tab2 which calls its own fragment, the EditTexts fragment  from tab1  remains and overlays the tab2 fragment

I think understand that what I am trying to do is fundamentally wrong that a fragment cannot call another fragment to replace itself? or that somehow I am not correctly removing the the previous fragments and something to do with backstack..???? or showing and hiding the xml?????

I am very new to this and completely confused! Please help...thank you in advance :)

Here is my code most taken from the android site http://developer.android.com/training/backward-compatible-ui/index.html using the TabCompat.zip sample

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.android.tabcompat;
public class MainActivity extends TabCompatActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

TabHelper tabHelper = getTabHelper();

CompatTab tab1Tab = tabHelper.newTab("tab1")
.setText(R.string.tab_tab1)
.setTabListener(new InstantiatingTabListener(this,"A", Tab1Fragment.class));
tabHelper.addTab(tab1Tab);

        CompatTab tab2Tab = tabHelper.newTab("tab2")
            .setText(R.string.tab_tab2)
            .setTabListener(new InstantiatingTabListener(this, "B", Tab2Fragment.class));
        tabHelper.addTab(tab2Tab);

        CompatTab tab3Tab = tabHelper.newTab("tab3")
                .setText(R.string.tab_tab3)
                .setTabListener(new InstantiatingTabListener(this,"C", Tab3Fragment.class));
        tabHelper.addTab(tab3Tab);
    }

    /**
     * Implementation of {@link CompatTabListener} to handle tab change events. This implementation
     * instantiates the specified fragment class with no arguments when its tab is selected.
     */
    public static class InstantiatingTabListener implements CompatTabListener {

        private final TabCompatActivity mActivity;
        private final Class mClass;


        /**
         * Constructor used each time a new tab is created.
         * @param activity The host Activity, used to instantiate the fragment
         * @param cls      The class representing the fragment to instantiate
         */
        public InstantiatingTabListener(TabCompatActivity activity, String tag, Class<? extends Fragment> cls) {
            mActivity = activity;
            mClass = cls;

        }

        /* The following are each of the ActionBar.TabListener Callback */
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(CompatTab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // Check if the fragment is already initialised
            Fragment fragment = tab.getFragment();
            if (fragment == null) {
                // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
                fragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
                tab.setFragment(fragment);
                ft.add(android.R.id.tabcontent, fragment, tab.getTag());
            } 
            else {
                // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
                ft.attach(fragment);
            }
        }


        public void onTabUnselected(CompatTab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            Fragment fragment = tab.getFragment();
            if (fragment != null) {  
            ft.detach(fragment);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(CompatTab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // User selected the already selected tab. Do nothing.

    } }
      }
```

**Tab1Fragment.java** this is where  the 'add button' is loaded

```
package com.example.android.tabcompat;

        public class Tab1Fragment extends Fragment{

        protected int position;
        //display the add tab1 button
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final Button btn = new Button (getActivity());
            btn.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
            btn.setText(R.string.btn_tab1);
            btn.setId(1);
            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
    //when button is clicked replace the button and display the tab1 form fragment


    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    Tab1FormFragment formFragment = new Tab1FormFragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(android.R.id.tabcontent, formFragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
                }

            });
            return btn;

        }
    }
```

**Tab1FormFragment.java** this fragment display a form of edittext views which it gets from layout file form.xml

```
package com.example.android.tabcompat;



   public class Tab1FormFragment extends Fragment {
    protected static final String ARG_POSITION = null;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
       Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.form, container, false);

      return myFragmentView;
     }

     }
```

**form.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/petForm"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
<ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_tab_photos" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/field_name"
            android:inputType="text" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextAge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/field_age"
            android:inputType="text" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextBreed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/field_breed"
            android:inputType="text" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinnerSex"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:entries="@array/sex_arrays"
            android:hint="@string/field_sex" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/savePet"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/save_record" />
    </LinearLayout>`
```

Comment: ok, so have done a bit more reading, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12114150/action-bar-tabs-having-two-fragments-one-being-dynamic-in-one-tab    and see that both my fragments need to be dynamic. so have replaced the form.xml with a dynamically created form instead using layoutparams. i still have th e overlapping problem tho....sigh

Comment: I have a suggestion.. You could probably combine your button fragment and the form fragment logic in the same fragment by using a ViewFlipper. The first child of the ViewFlipper will be your button, when a user presses on the button you can use the ViewFlipper's method "setDisplayedChild"  to show your form fragment. That way you avoid having to replace the fragment and you still get the same desired effect.

Comment: Where does R.id.tabcontent live? Is it on the layout for MainActivity?

Answer (score 0):

You could try calling the non-action-bar tab (the one you said has a bunch of EditText) along with giving that instance of a fragment a tag i.e. in your dynamic button's onClick method add this line after initiating your Tab1formFragment:

`getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.tabcontent, formFragment, "FORM_FRAG").addToBackStack(null).commit();`

And changing your action bar tab transactions by adding a check for formFragment instance:
`if(getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FORM_FRAG")!=null)`
`getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FORM_FRAG")).commit()`

Additionally you could use replace() fragment transactions in your onTabSelected() method instead of attach() and add().